# Teradata Error on Unicode delimited identifier or an 'UDFCALLNAME'

Tags: syntax-error, teradata

Trying to figure out why I am getting a Teradata exception: [Teradata Database] [3707] Syntax error, expected something like a name or a Unicode delimited identifier or an 'UDFCALLNAME' keyword between ')' and the

````
select ma.MHKAUDITLOGINTERNALID  as id, 
cast(MHK_CONTENT as varchar (8000)) as MHK_CONTENT,
AUDITDATETIME, CREATEDBY, MHKAPPEALSINTERNALID, MHKIREINTERNALID
   from vcoreMEDHOK_MHK_Audit as ma
   Where ma.AUDITDATETIME >= DATE '2021-08-01'
   and ma.MHKAPPEALSINTERNALID Is NOT NULL
   or  ma.AUDITDATETIME >= DATE '2021-08-01'
   and ma.MHKAPPEALSINTERNALID <> ' ' 
   or ma.AUDITDATETIME >= DATE '2021-08-01'
   and ma.MHKAPPEALSINTERNALID <> ' - ' )
select dt.id, TokenNum,regexp_replace(MHK_CONTENT, '<b>|</b>') as NewContent--- |<\/b>   --- ADT, MHKAPPEALSINTERNALID,MHKIREINTERNALID ,CreatedBy,AUDITDATETIME, CREATEDBY, MHKAPPEALSINTERNALID, MHKIREINTERNALID,                                 --- oreplace (Token,'<BR>','')
FROM TABLE    (RegExp_Split_To_Table(t.id, t.MHK_CONTENT, '<br/>*', 'i'))  --- split whenever '<BR/>' occurs t.TokenNum, t.MHK_CONTENT, t.ADT, t.MHKAPPEALSINTERNALID,t.MHKIREINTERNALID,t.CreatedBy,    ---'<b>|<\/b>|<BR>|</BR>|<br/>| - *', 'i' --- '<b>|<\/b>|<br/>|<BR>|</BR>*', 'i')
RETURNS (id BIGINT, TokenNum INT, MHK_CONTENT VARCHAR(8000), CreatedBy VARCHAR(100)))))as dt ```
````

Comment: Check for mismatched parentheses.

Comment: You've got 8 open parens, and 12 close parens, ignoring comments

Comment: What's your SQL client? Studio will indicate syntax errror while typing with a red x on the left and a dotted red line where the parser got stuck. SQL Assistant is also showing the dotted line, but only if you connect using .NET and after trying to run it. The parser complanins about the closing ) before the 2nd Select. You got two Selects, one of them must be wrapped in a Dervied Table or a CTE.

Comment: i tried to get a coworker to help me, i remember back in the day didnt sql server studio or was it redgate, its been a minute. I'm using TOAD 5.2.0.276 (64 bit)

Comment: Maybe you really have two separate queries, and you want a semi-colon before the second select?  I think you've still got an extra close paren in there, right before the second select.

Comment: Great minds, I was just thinking how could I join them to have the first 1 run and then the 2nd. might clear up.

Answer (score 0):

OK i did correct that it got snippy with me again:  [Teradata Database] [3706] Syntax error: expected something between a string or a Unicode character literal and ')'.

Comment: Right now im just rolling them separately, I'd like to join them but i need the result set of the first in order to do the 2nd query. then I can do a derived or CTE. unless im not thinking correctly.